# SQL in Matlab: First day/date of every month in dataset

Tags: sql, matlab

i saw some other post about my question, but mine is a bit more specific i think, but also easy for the pros.

I have a table (name=List) like this:

```
    date      price
'2017-01-03'    12
'2017-01-04'    10
'2017-01-05'    11
'2017-02-01'     8
'2017-02-02'     6
'2017-03-02'    14
...
```

And a second one (name=Constituants) with the first of every month:

```
    Date
'2017-01-01'
'2017-02-01'
'2017-03-01'
```

Those are given. Maybe i don´t even have to use second one. In the end I want to have the date for every first day available in every month in 'List', like this:

```
date          price
'2017-01-03'    12
'2017-02-01'     8
'2017-03-02'    14
...
```

My try:

```
Select min(List.Date) 
from List inner join Constituents 
    on List.Date=Constituents.Date
where datepart(year,List.Date)=datepart(year,Constituents.Date)
    and datepart(month,List.Date)=datepart(month,Constituents.Date)
```

Out of this query i don´t get any value (error message in german). Please help.

Comment: `Select min(List.Date) from List inner join Constituents on and List.Date=Constituents.Date where datepart(year,List.Date)=datepart(year,Constituents.Date) and datepart(month,List.Date)=datepart(month,Constituents.Date)` You have an extra `and` just after the where.

Comment: Ah yes. Thank you. But that´s not the problem, because i shortened my query for this question. After `where` i had `and Constituants.Date<#01/01/2007#`

Comment: What is the error message? Can you translate it to English?

Comment: `Error using COM.ADODB_Connection/Execute
Invoke Error, Dispatch Exception:
Source: Microsoft Access Database Engine
Description: (for at least one parameter you didn´t stated a value)` Does this help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try to do something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM List
WHERE Date IN (
    SELECT   MIN(List.Date)
    FROM     List
    GROUP BY MONTH(List.Date), YEAR(List.Date)
  )
```